# How to get an Ubuntu remote desktop when I only have root SSH access?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, ssh, remote-desktop

I have root SSH access to a remote Ubuntu 17 machine. I'm working locally on macOS 10.12. I want to be able to get a remote desktop to the Ubuntu machine. How do I do this? What do I need to install/enable on the Ubuntu machine? What to I need to install enable on my local macOS?

Comment: I'd suggest you read this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/149058/how-can-i-add-a-desktop-gui-to-a-command-line-ubuntu-installation

Comment: Is the PC running Ubuntu Server (has no GUI) or Ubuntu Desktop?

Comment: I may be wrong but that answers how to do it for a local machine (I know hes talking about a VM but its essentially the same thing as a local machine). It doesnt cover the process for doing it remotely.

Comment: @Moses I'm not entirely sure. Since the remote PC is from a hosting provider (Vultr.com), I would assume Server.

Comment: Don't know the full details, but basically: you install a X-window server on your Mac [(yes, a server)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Software_architecture), you install the GUI apps on the remote with possibly a X-window manager (no need for the X server there), and you login with SSH allowing X-tunneling (`-X`) so that the apps on the remote can connect to your X-window server.

Comment: `This client–server terminology ... often confuses new X users` Yep. That may have been the mental hurdle that was tripping me up. Thanks.